# Run Test Suite in Play 1.2.4

Tags: junit, playframework-1.x, test-suite

I am unable to run JUnit test suites in 1.2.4 since the command play test-only is not available. Please respond to the same in case there can be a fix for it without upgrading to higher versions of Play.

Comment: Yes I am able to run a test. But need to run a specific test suite. I can find the way of running it in Play 2.0 by using test-only which is not available in 1.2.4. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can run your tests using the command:
`play test`

More information can be found here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/test

Comment: Yes I am able to run a test. But need to run a specific test suite.
I can find the way of running it in Play 2.0 by using test-only which is not available in 1.2.4. Please help

Answer (score 0):

### IDE:

If you are using an ide like eclipse you can run your **junit tests from within the ide**.

### Command Line:

There are also the following two options for the command line:

**Option 1:**

```
play test
```

This runs the app in test mode. You can then run all tests via a browser interface available at:

`http://localhost:9000/@tests` (or your custom port if you changed it)

**Option 2:**

```
play auto-test
```

Runs the tests automatically without opening the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Run your app in test mode:

```
play test
```

Then open the following URL:

```
http://localhost:9000/@tests
```

You'll be able to all, or individual, test classes to run. Unfortunately there's no way to run an individual test.

Answer (score 0):

Try using testOnly as the command, instead of test-only.